# Cant make mod_wsgi-3.3 in trying to use it with xampp and django

Tags: django, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi, wsgi

```
raz@T43:~/Downloads/mod_wsgi-3.3$ sudo ./configure --with-apxs=/opt/lampp/bin/apxs --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.6
checking Apache version... 2.2.14
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
raz@T43:~/Downloads/mod_wsgi-3.3$ sudo make
/opt/lampp/bin/apxs -c -I/usr/include/python2.6 -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/python2.6/config  -lpython2.6 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/opt/lampp/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -O3 -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/lampp/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/opt/lampp/lib/mysql -I/opt/lampp/include -L/opt/lampp/lib  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -pthread -I/opt/lampp/include  -I/opt/lampp/include   -I/opt/lampp/include -I/opt/lampp/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
mod_wsgi.c:135: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

I cant find what's wrong. Any one have an idea? Python seams to work in all other regards

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the 'dev' package for Python installation you are using.

Error message is described in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Missing_Python_Header_Files